# Инициализация вектора через фигурные скобки

Tags: c++, вектор

Я новичок, учусь по книге Страуструпа "Программирование. Принципы и практика с использованием С++".
Дошел до темы "Векторы" и решил попробовать написать в программе вот такую конструкцию:

```
vector<int> v = {5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8};
```

На что компилятор ругнулся:

> error in c++98 must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'

Собственно, вопрос: как решить эту ошибку?

Comment: Использую компилятор GCC и среду Code::Blocks 10.05

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сконструировать свой vector, используя конструктор со списком инициализации (http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), который не поддерживается старым компилятором с++ 98. Подключите с++11 ( в разных ide это делается по-разному, так что погуглите)

Comment: Либо переведите компилятор в режим С++11, либо перестаньте использовать конструкции, специфичные для С++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Списки инициализации для контейнеров появились в С++11. Компилятор сообщает, что вы сейчас в режиме С++98.

Вам следует писать так:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(5);
v.push_back(7);
v.push_back(9);
v.push_back(6);
v.push_back(8);
```

Или включить режим С++11.

Если честно, никогда не видел Code::Blocks, но гугл утверждает что нужно сделать это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Cпасибо вам большое за ваш ответ! Он помог, я включил режм С++11. Но теперь вылезла новая ошибка "no matching function for call to 'Vector<int>::Vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)" :с. Не могли бы вы помочь и с этой ошибкой? То ли я гуглю плохо, то ли только у меня такие руки кривые, не могу найти(

Comment: @niki4iko, именно `Vector`? С большой буквы?

Comment: Да, с большой. Но писал в коде я с маленькой, так же как написано в топике

Comment: @niki4iko, возможно у вас слишком старый gcc. Онлайн-компилятор(GCC 4.9.2) [нормально компилирует](http://cpp.sh/2ia4p) такой код.

Comment: Да, проблема оказалась в этом. Спасибо вам огромное ещё раз! Жаль, что не хватает рейтинга поставить вам плюс :(

Comment: @niki4iko, не в плюсах счастье. Мы, начинающие программисты, должны помогать друг другу :)